# Splitting partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How come 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
when 
$$
u = x\; cos \theta - y\; sin \theta
$$
$$
v = x\; sin \theta + y\; cos\theta
$$
It seems like that formula is twice as great on the right side. (Are the definitions of $u$ and $v$ even relevant?)

ANSWER: This is the definition of the chain rule for partial derivatives when $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y.$ It is irrelevant to the definitions of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y).$

Comment: Use the chain rule for a real value function...

Comment: Doesn't that play in to my question though about not being equal?

Comment: You defined what $u$ and $v$ are, what about $f$?

Comment: I was told the definition of $f$ is irrelevant.

Comment: It is, but $f$ must be a funcion of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Ah, so I suppose what I am really asking is a proof of the chain rule for partial derivatives.

Comment: @LaikeTren That is the kind of proof you will find in any mathematical analysis textbook.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof, but a demonstration: Had $f=f(u,v)$ only where u and v were independent variables, you'd get a total change in f from changes in both $u$ and $v$

$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} du +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} dv
$$
I suspect you are comfortable with that. As it turns out, $u$ and $v$ are themselves functions of independent variables x and y (assuming $\theta$ is only a parameter here). So

$$
du = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dy \\
dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy  
$$

Substitute for these values of $du,dv$
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dy )  +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx +  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy )
$$

Group terms in dx, dy together and you have your result.

$$
df = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right) dx + 
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right) dy
$$